# Marklogic: mlcp permission issue while importing

Tags: marklogic, mlcp

I am on Marklogic 8.0.4 mlcp.
Following is the command I run:

> ./bin/mlcp.sh import -host localhost -username admin -password admin
>   -input_file_path /file/path/to/RDF.owl -input_file_type RDF

This is my log:

```
6/03/12 12:07:05 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner: Content type: XML
16/03/12 12:07:05 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
16/03/12 12:07:05 ERROR contentpump.LocalJobRunner: Error running task:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.marklogic.contentpump.utilities.PermissionUtil.getDefaultPermissions(PermissionUtil.java:84)
    at com.marklogic.contentpump.RDFReader.initialize(RDFReader.java:278)
    at com.marklogic.contentpump.LocalJobRunner$TrackingRecordReader.initialize(LocalJobRunner.java:439)
    at com.marklogic.contentpump.LocalJobRunner$LocalMapTask.call(LocalJobRunner.java:373)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/03/12 12:07:05 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner:  completed 0%
16/03/12 12:07:05 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner: com.marklogic.mapreduce.ContentPumpStats:
16/03/12 12:07:05 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner: OUTPUT_RECORDS_COMMITTED: 0
16/03/12 12:07:05 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner: OUTPUT_RECORDS_FAILED: 0
16/03/12 12:07:05 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner: Total execution time: 0 sec
```

Not sure what is the issue, the user admin has all the privileges. I also restarted MarkLogic once.

Any pointers?

Comment: I am on Mac el capitan

Comment: You may have hit a bug in MLCP's RDF reader. Can you file a bug report at MarkLogic Support?

Comment: Are there a couple lines of the OWL file that are enough to trigger the error? If so, could you post those?

Answer (score 1):

If you used windows machine please try this below mentioned MLCP query.

```
mlcp.bat IMPORT -host localhost -port 8010 -username test  -password test -input_file_path "C:/" -output_uri_replace "C:/,''" -output_uri_prefix /URI
```